# iPhone : initing plist field value with the value of another field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

Is there a way to init the field in plist file with the value from another field.

Please dont suggest to modify the objective c code to read the value that I need, I use third party tool which does read from different fields ... I just want to init the value of one plist field with the value of the another field

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) tool. If you need something more specific, please, restate your question.

Comment: Yes, it's for MacOS. It's very popular tool to work with plists from scripts

Comment: Thanks for answer@! I've forgot to mention I was looking a solution for iOS.

Comment: @jackal, in that case I don't understand your problem. Probably you'll get an answer if you restate your question.